# Call a Rake task repeatedly

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a Rake task that calls a number of other Rake tasks, one repeatedly:

```
task :cycle do
  Rake::Task["db:work"].invoke(0)
  Rake::Task["db:work"].invoke(nil)
end

task :work, [:version,] do |t, args|    
  if args[:version]
    puts " * Migrating to version #{args[:version]}"
  else
    puts " * Migrating to latest version"
  end
end
```

When I run the `cycle` task, it only runs the `work` task once:

```
$ rake db:cycle
 * Migrating to version 0
```

I expected this:

```
$ rake db:cycle
 * Migrating to version 0
 * Migrating to latest version
```

Is there a way to force Rake to run both tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake` is OSS, btw.

`Rake::Task#invoke` checks that the task was not previously invoked and [early returns if it was](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/f0c7528788e825e68051f93672ec940aac87b7f1/lib/rake/task.rb#L200-L209). I do not know much about `rake`, but resetting this instance variable should do the trick.

```
Rake::Task["db:work"].tap do |task|
  task.invoke(0)
  task.instance_variable_set(:@already_invoked, false)
  task.invoke(nil)
end
```

Comment: What does OSS mean?

Comment: Open Source Software.

Comment: Thanks for sharing `Class#tap` too.